# Why trim zeros from decimal part php not accurate for .00?

Tags: php

I have this float value `1290.00` and I would like to trim the zeros on the right in the cleanest way to get `1290`, but Why I got `129` if using `trim` function?

Code:

```php
<?php
$var = '1290.00';
printf ("value: %s -> %s\n", $var, trim($var, '.00'));
```

The output:

```
value: 1290.00 -> 129
```

I have seen different solutions to it by not using trim function, but why is trim not working? I also tried with GoLang and got the same behavior.

Comment: you are treating the `float` as a string

Comment: Trim takes a list of characters as second parameter. You are saying to trim `.` and `0`s.

Comment: You are not trimming `'.00'` you are telling trim to remove all `0` and all `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim removes characters from the end, individually, not as a phrase. It removes all found characters until it can't find any more in the list. So it removes the 0, the 0, the period, then the 0. In this case, I would recommend either `round` or `number_format`

```
number_format($var, 0, '', ''); // 1290
```

Comment: And simply type cast to int; `(int)$var;` which does the same as number_format

Comment: `from the end` - maybe worth pointing out that it trims leading and trailing characters - which further reinforces that it's the wrong tool for the job at hand. @Martin casting to an int does not round whereas number format will - depending on the use case, that usually matters.

Comment: @AD7six You're right. I was saying "from the end" in this case because the matching characters were at the end, but trim does remove from both ends.

Answer (score 0):

`trim` doesn't work like that.  You only specify the characters you want to trim once, and two periods are used to specify a range. It will then trim all of those characters from the end.

A more efficient method might be `intval($var)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage, note that `number_format()` also rounds the value (see the first example of the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format)). If you need to truncate the number you could use [`floor()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php):

```php
number_format(1.9, 0, '', '');    // string(1) "2"
floor(1.9);                       // 1
```